# MVC3 - Send single item from bound complex view to an ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

any feedback gratefully received...

What I'd like to do is generate a list of complex types within individual forms and then submit them, one at a time, to an ActionResult.

I have the code to define, display and submit them (see below) but when the object is received because of the [x] prefixes nothing is received and the values are null.

I have managed to hack something together but it is ugly and there *must* be something better!

### Full description

I'm displaying a list of complex types on a view.

**Model**

```
public class TestItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

From **Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ICollection<TestItem> model = new List<TestItem> {
       new TestItem {  ID=1, Name="aaa", Description="aaa desc"},
       new TestItem {  ID=2, Name="bbb", Description="bbb desc"},
       new TestItem {  ID=3, Name="ccc", Description="ccc desc"},
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

...to a **view**

```
<h2>Test</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)
```

that uses an **EditorTemplate**

```
@model MultiBindTest.Models.TestItem

@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Home"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(i=>i.ID)
    <ul>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Name)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Description)
            @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Description)
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

To generate html with multiple forms like this...

```
<form action="/Home/DoSomething" method="post">
    <input data-val="true" 
           data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." 
           data-val-required="The ID field is required." 
           name="[2].ID" 
           type="hidden"
           value="3" />    
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[2].Name" type="text" value="ccc" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="">Description</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[2].Description" type="text" value="ccc desc" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>;
```

**Note** the [2]. prefix on the fields.  This is repeated on all instances, so the first form fields are prefided [0]. the second form is [1]. etc.

When the individual forms are submitted to the following ActionResult

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(TestItem model)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Name);

    return View("Index");
}
```

The model item is always null.

The hack is...

```
    public ActionResult DoSomething2(FormCollection form)
    {
        string id = form.GetKey(1).Split('.').First();
        string x = form[string.Format("{0}.ID", id)].ToString();
        return View("Home");
    }
```

Which is nasty and I **really** don't want to use it!

### **EDIT**

I have also tried

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(TestItem[] model)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Name);

    return View("Index");
}
```

Which works... if I click on the first form on the page, but model is null if I click on any subsequent forms.  Maybe I am on the right path with this....

When I click on the first item it's POSTing(via firebug)

```
[0].Description aaa desc
[0].ID          1
[0].Name        aaa
```

and the controller receives

```
testItem                  {MultiBindTest.Models.TestItem[1]}
testItem[0]               {MultiBindTest.Models.TestItem}
testItem[0].Description   "aaa desc"
testItem[0].ID            1
testItem[0].Name          "aaa"
```

If I click on the second page on the form it POSTs

```
[1].Description bbb desc
[1].ID          2
[1].Name        bbb
```

and receives

```
testItem    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the editor for `TestItem` as partial

```
<h2>
    Test</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/TestItem", item)
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is the problem would it not be easier to use something like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething([Bind.Prefix("MyPrefix")]TestItem model)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(model.Name);

    return View("Index");
}
```

For pointers on how to define your own prefixes since you are using a custom Editor template check http://thatextramile.be/blog/2011/01/prefixing-input-elements-of-partial-views-with-asp-net-mvc/

It is about partial views but I think it gives information that applies to your case.

Comment: The issue is there is no 'prefix', just the numeric loop identifier. Thanks for the link, I'll see if I can artificially add a prefix and parse it out!